# How to lookup corresponding encoded elements with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two series of data, each value is a list.

```
    amenities                                       amenity_ids
0   [TV,Wifi,Kitchen,"Free parking on premises","I...   [64, 1,129, 66, 4, 134...]
1   [TV,Wifi,Kitchen,"Family/kid friendly",Washer,...   [1, 129, 2, 4, 71, 8, 77...]
```

The sets of amenities and their ids and are likely to correspond most of the time.

How can I map amenities with their corresponding ids?

I must clarify, that the position of elements don't correspond each other, but the sets of the both lists should correspond, given the data are clean the particular row.

Having around 7000 rows we hopefully can decode the corresponding key:value pairs

Thank you!

Comment: show an example of your expected output

Comment: In this small example none of them seem to correspond, unless there should be a mapping dict for each row? Please elaborate, and share expected output

Comment: @yatu, that the position of elements don't correspond each other, but the sets of the both lists should correspond, given the data are clean the particular row.

Having around 7000 rows we hopefully can decode the corresponding key:value pairs

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, Lets say we have this df:

```
                                       amenities               ids
0  [TV, Wifi, Kitchen, Free parking on premises]  [64, 1, 129, 66]
1       [TV, Wifi, Kitchen, Family/kid friendly]    [1, 129, 2, 4]
```

You can do this:

```
pd.concat([df['amenities'].explode(),df['ids'].explode()],axis=1)

                  amenities  ids
0                        TV   64
0                      Wifi    1
0                   Kitchen  129
0  Free parking on premises   66
1                        TV    1
1                      Wifi  129
1                   Kitchen    2
1       Family/kid friendly    4
```

ps. You have to upgrade pandas to the latest version.

Comment: in fact, `df[['amenities']].explode('amenities')` doesn't work on my system either.

Comment: @QuangHoang You have to upgrade pandas

Comment: If it works only with the very most version, you probably want to mention that in your answer.

Comment: @billy-bonaros,, that the position of elements don't correspond each other, but the sets of the both lists should correspond, given the data are clean the particular row.

Having around 7000 rows we hopefully can decode the corresponding key:value pairs

Answer (score 0):

You may use Zip function to create a dictionary object for mapping values with amenities. For example:

```
l1 = ["TV","Kitchen","wifi"]
l2 = [20,40,15]
d= dict(zip(l1,l2))
```

Output: `{'TV': 20, 'Kitchen': 40, 'wifi': 15}`

Comment: the position of elements don't correspond each other, but the sets of the both lists should correspond, given the data are clean the particular row. Having around 7000 rows we hopefully can decode the corresponding key:value pairs. Thank you!